# TypeScript with JSON import file and const literal

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this code:

```js
import * as config from 'src/app-config.json'
import { Configuration, CacheLocation } from 'msal'

export function MSALConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  return {
    auth: {
      clientId: config.auth.clientId,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: test as CacheLocation,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
  }
}
```

When importing the JSON file all objects become of type `string`, `boolean`, `number`, ... but not a literal type. To circumvent this one can use the `as const` as [documented here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions).

So I would've expected this to work:

```js
cacheLocation: config.cache.cacheLocation as const,
```

But it's not accepted:

[image]

Although when it's in a normal `string` format not coming from a JSON file it works fine:

```js
const type = 'localStorage' as const

cache: {
      cacheLocation: type,
```

Am I missing something obvious here?